# Is there any way to turn off Parse's (api) default debugging? (Xcode swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, parse-platform

Parse produces a lot of output to the console and it clogs up so that I can't see other output which I'm looking for. Is there any way to toggle Parse printing to the console? I'm in Xcode beta. I understand I can do searches and filters but it is time consuming.

Comment: I am using parse too and it wont give me any log unless it is error and you should always handle errors... or what log messages do you mean?

Comment: @MazelTov so I've realised it's just web requests in general and Parse is part of that. Is there any way to turn off that?

Comment: i still dont know what you want achieve or what is the problem here...